# A frog with 2022 lily pads, always hops on a larger numbered lily pad : Probability and Permutations and Combinations question

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations, combinations

Lily pads numbered from 1 to 2022 are placed on a pond. Bruno the frog starts on
pad 1. Every moment he picks a integer greater than the integer on the pad he is
standing on, uniformly at random, and jumps to the corresponding lily pad. The
probability he lands on the pad numbered 2000 at some instant is a
b
, where a, b are
coprime positive integers. Find the value of a × b.

Heres what I did

The frog *has* to have the starting point 1 and ending point 2022. Any other point in between these two values he can either choose or not choose. So number of paths from 1 to 2022 he can take is 2^2020.
The number of paths he can take which have the number 2020 in them is 2^2019.
Therefore a = 2^2019 and b = 2^2020

which gives me $a×b=2$ which seems off to me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $p(n)$ be the probability that Bruno lands on pad $n$. Clearly, $p(1)=1$. For $n>1$ we have:

$$p(n) = \sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\frac{p(i)}{2022-i}$$

We get this by adding up all of the conditional probabilities that Bruno hops to $n$ directly from some $i < n$. This gives $p(2) = \frac{1}{2021}$. For $n>2$:

$$p(n) = \sum_{i=1}^{n-2}\frac{p(i)}{2022-i}+\frac{p(n-1)}{2023-n}=\frac{2024-n}{2023-n}\cdot p(n-1)$$

We claim that $p(n) = \frac{1}{2023 - n}$ for $n > 1$. Clearly, this is true for $n=2$. Assuming it is true for $n=k-1$, we have:

$$p(k) = \frac{2024-k}{2023-k}\cdot \frac{1}{2023 - (k-1)} = \frac{1}{2023-k}$$

Thus, the claim is true by induction, giving $\boxed{p(2000) = \frac{1}{23}}$.

Comment: I understand your solution but I dont get where I went wrong with my approach. Could you please help me out? Thanks!

Comment: The issue is that not all paths are equally likely (e.g. 2022 will occur with probability 1, even though it is only in half of the paths).